# Passing HTML and CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, variables

I need to find a way to pass the visible div to javascript. This may not even be the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish, so I'm open for other suggestions.

All my site content opens in a single overlay. When a button is clicked in the navigation, that content opens in the overlay. When another button is clicked, that content replaces the current content in the overlay. And so on.

The best identifier (that I've spotted) of which overlay is open, is (CSS) `display:block`...
and all the hidden divs are `display:none`....

So I want to pass which div has the `display:block` to javascript (Note: all the div's have unique ID's)

I'm sure this is something easy, But I can't seem to find it...

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Comment: Well the easiest way to achieve what you are saying is just making a map in javascript.

So set `var a = 0;` for the first screen, `a = 1` for the second, etc.

And then just check the variable when you need to update the visibility?

Comment: I am curious why you don't just capture the id off of the click event. If you put the id in a variable, the last one displayed would always be there.

Comment: @Yuri you lost me there, I'm not great with JS....

Comment: @COBOLdinosaur How do I do that? That sounds useful... As I said above, I'm pretty shaky when it comes to JS...

Comment: @brett When the the function to swap in the new layer is executed it must use document.getElementById() or some other method to get a handle for the element.  Therefore you should be able to save the reference to the same handle with somevar=document.getElementById('xxx'). or just grab the id.

Comment: @brett Basically keep track of which screen is currently being displayed using a global variable. That way you can always find which screen is being displayed by asking what the value of that variable is. And update the variable on each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each HTML element in JS has style property. You can read and change element style by calling for example

```
document.getElementById('id').style.display
```

So you don't need to pass anything to JS, it's already there.

Comment: Sure, but the complexity of this is much higher than keeping track with a global variable.

Comment: Would this then pass the id of the element into JS as a variable named the same as the html element??

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I try to be more specific.
In JS you only need identifiers of this overlay divs, you can store them in array. Then you can iterate through this array, and check witch element is visible like so:

    `var ids = [ 'id1', 'id2' ];
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) { if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display == 'block') { /* do something */ } }`

Comment: if div 1 is called "about-me" and div 2 is called "about-you" would it get plugged in like this:
`var ids = [ 'about-me', 'about-you' ]` 

Also, would this update every time the display:block changes?

Comment: @Brett - that's the way you should use it.

If you want to have actual information just wrap it into a function
`var ids = [ 'about-me', 'about-you' ]; function getActiveOverlayId(){ for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; ++i) { if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.display == 'block') { return ids[i]; } } }`
Then you just call this function whenever you need to know visible overlay id: `alert(getActiveOverlayId());`

Comment: Where `return ids[i]` is, I can place some javascript to do something, correct?? And if I call the function from an onclick like this `onclick="getActiveOverlayId()"` will it work??

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question it sounds like you need to identify which of your divs is the visible one.  The easiest way to do that is add a class to all your divs with content, you can then use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to get a list of them and loop through to find which one is visible one based on a `display` property of `block`.

```
<div class="content" style="display: none";>a</div>
<div class="content" style="display: block;">b</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none";>c</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none";>d</div>
<div class="content" style="display: none";>e</div>

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content");

for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) 
{
     if (elements[i].style.display == 'block')
     {
          // elements[i] = this is the visable div 
          alert('This elements[i] has a display of block; contents =  ' + elements[i].innerText);  
     }
}
```

The above script will output/alert 'b' as it is the visible div found.
[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln5KA/)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Will this update every time the display changes? and what is the output that I could use in the next function I need to make? Does it just output "b"?